# CKEDITOR browse and insert image issue

Tags: javascript, php

How to browse/insert image in Ckeditor by using opencart's filemanager(image manager) ?

I hope can get to know how to insert an image in ckeditor by using the opencart image manager and code sample

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Open CKEditor's config.js file. You can usually find it in the "ckeditor" folder of your OpenCart installation.

2)Find the line where the "filebrowserBrowseUrl" configuration is defined and change its value to the URL of your OpenCart's file manager. For example:

```
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/admin/index.php?route=common/filemanager';
```

3)Save the config.js file and close it.

4)In your OpenCart backend, go to the page where you have CKEditor integrated. You should now see a "Browse Server" button in the Image Properties dialog box.

5)When you click the "Browse Server" button, a new window should open displaying your OpenCart's file manager. You can now browse your image folders and select the image you want to insert.

6)Once you've selected an image, click the "Insert" button and the image should be inserted into the CKEditor instance.

--Note: The above steps assume that you have the OpenCart's file manager enabled in your backend. If not, you may need to install and enable it first.